# Sort date list dynamically with dates matching today's date always at top of list

Tags: vba

Would really appreciate your help.
Have a list of dates for deliveries ahead of time. Would like when sheet is select deliveries expected for today is show at the top of the date list. So the list dynamically reorders every day putting expected deliveries matching today's date at the top. Nothing working for me. Thanks.

```
    Sub todaysList()

If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$4").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
    xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
Else
    Selection.AutoFilter

End If

End Sub
```

Amended Code: --- Good, but still does not sort dates so dates matching today's date are move to the top of the list of dates. Left the else statement in because it allows the button with the Macro attached to function as the filter and also as a switch to turn the filter on and off when clicked a second time.

```
Sub todaysList()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RECEIPTING")

If ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$4").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
    Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, _
    Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
Else
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you can start by recording a macro while you sort the sheet by date the way you want, then look at the code and remove all `select` and `activate` statements - you will end up with most of the code you need for your requirement. You can call this macro from the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event of the sheet's module. If you have a specific issue with that code ask for help

Comment: will give that a go and update you. thanks for your time and keep well.

Comment: I can build the code from the macro to filter to any date in the list and I can also get it to run when sheet activates. What I don't get is how to set Now() or Today as the filter criteria so it checks what the days date is and filter to that date dynamically.

Comment: Please include the code in the OP, and a small sample of the dates (the "before" and "after")

Comment: This code when added to a button filters the dates matching today's date but I'd like to have it run dynamically having it reorder list placing dates matching today's date at the top. So if I have these three dates 02/07/2017, 03/07/2017 and 04/07/2017 and I opened the sheet today it should put 03/07/2017 at the top of the list. If I open sheet tomorrow it should put 04/07/2017 at the top of the list – Junior 35 mins ago

Comment: Not sure I understand: in your question you want to sort, but in your code you use the AutoFilter. You want to filter so only today's dates will be visible? or you want to sort? If sorting, you have dates before and after today: so you want to sort oldest to newest or newest to oldest?

Comment: Just reread your comment; so sorry for being unclear ... it's the newby in me talking. I would like to sort the date column so the dates matching the day's date i.e. Today / Now() are shown at the top of the list everyday. I'm filtering because I can't figure out how to do the other. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I CRACKED IT!!!. There are a few things you need to setup first.

> 1. Create a Column on the sheet containing your dates which you can leave visible or hide (your choice) - Call it what you like, mine is called  'Prioritiser'.
> 2. In this column you want to store the results the 'date in your date column - today's date' i.e. 'Date' function.
>      If the date has passed the result will be a negative number.
>      If the date is equal to today's date the result will be 0.
>      If the date is ahead i.e. in the future the result will be a positive number.

- The code explained:-

  > A: I perform a Row count.
  >
  > B: I loop through each records date with a For Next
  >      loop starting at Row 2 (below the header).
  >
  > C: For Dates records past
  >   and future I record a '0' in the 'Prioritiser' Column
  >
  > D: For dates matching today's date I record a '1'
  >
  > E: I then run a sort filter on the 'Prioritise' column putting all the 1s at the top of the list
  >
  > F: I attach the code the worksheet's 'Active' state

  Result:

  > Every time the sheet is selected dates matching the current day will be moved to the top.
  >
  > I'm sure you guys can refine the code making it slicker and more
  >   efficient. Keep well and enjoy.

HERE IT IS:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim C1 As Long
Dim rowCount, I As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("RECEIPTING")
rowCount = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To rowCount
    C1 = ws.Range("G" & I).Value - Date
        If C1 = 0 Then
            ws.Range("N" & I) = 1
        Else
            ws.Range("N" & I) = 0
        End If
Next I

If ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RECEIPTING").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter

Else
    ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter

End If

End Sub
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

Filter:

---

```
Public Sub ShowToday()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    ws.Range("$A$1:$M$5").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
                                     Criteria1:=xlFilterToday, _
                                     Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
End Sub
```

---

Sort:

---

```
Public Sub SortByDateAscending()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("G1:G5"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A1:M5")
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub SortByDateDescending()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("G1:G5"), Order:=xlDescending
        .SetRange Range("A1:M5")
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating the use of 'ws.AutoFilter as Nothing' in a If statement, was not aware I could use it like that. I've left the Else statement in because it allows the button the macro is attached to to function as the  filter and also a switch to turn the filter on and off. Thank you too for suggesting the other two examples, however, they don't solve the problem because they sort all dates Ascending or all dates Descending. I'd like the dates matching the date of the day 1,e, Now() or Today to be moved to the top of the list. Hope this helps. Keep well and thanks again.